# Letter spacing and Font size for limited amount of characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

OK, I have a few dynamic controls on my page which have limited amount of letters I can enter.
So I need to make a formula which calculates the letter spacing using the height and width of the control and a number of max letters. I need to also calculate the Font size using the same variables.
The result is that the textbox is filled with the text completly and all the possible letters are printed and it fits.

So let me try to represent this in code so people can relate.

```
H = getHeight();
W = getWidth();
TheItemT.Style.Add("letter-spacing", ((18 * (W / 18) / TheItemT.MaxLength) * 0.46) + "px");
//This was my prototype. It works in some cases where the control isnt too big. 18 and 0.46 are random variables that make it look good.
TheItemT.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontSize, (18 * (W / 18) / TheItemT.MaxLength).ToString() + "px");
```

Problem with my code is that it doesn't use the height and I can't wrap around my head around the math to make it work. To be honest I pulled this out of my ass and it sort of worked.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: you cannot strectch letters but you can play with line-height . codepen or fiddle somewhere ?

Comment: Is it a textarea? That is, multiple lines?

Comment: No its not multiple lines. And I can stretch letters. Font-size changes both width and height.